# How can I get tuple values (from a class) in my main function?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tuples, python-multiprocessing, eye-tracking

I am using multiprocesssing in Python 3.5.

```
 #Multiprocessing

def main():

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p1", target=datac)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p2", target=test)
p2.start()
p1.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

There are two processes=>
  1.test
  2.datac

Test:

```
def test():
#a=0
while 1:
    #if 'gaze_point' in gaze_data_callback(gaze_data):
     #   data = gaze_data_callback['gaze_point']

      #  if s == 0:
       #     x = data[0] * 1920
        #    y = data[1] * 1080
         #   return [x, y]
    #a+=1
    for x in range(0, 10):
        print("We're on time %d" % (x))
    print('Waiting..')
    #time.sleep(5)
```

Datac:

```
def datac():
while 1:
    tmp = eye.__new__(eye)
    tmp.__init__()
    print(tmp)
```

This is the class:

```
class eye(object):
    def gaze_data_callback(gaze_data):
            left_3d = gaze_data['left_gaze_point_in_user_coordinate_system']
            right_3d = gaze_data['right_gaze_point_in_user_coordinate_system']
        #Get the gaze point of both eyes
            gaze_point = ((left_3d), (right_3d))
            gaze_point = tuple(mean(gaze_point, axis=0))
            print("3d gaze:",gaze_point)
            my_eyetracker.subscribe_to(tr.EYETRACKER_GAZE_DATA, gaze_data_callback, as_dictionary=True)
            time.sleep(5)

            my_eyetracker.unsubscribe_from(tr.EYETRACKER_GAZE_DATA, gaze_data_callback)
            return (gaze_point)
```

I want to print the gaze point but it is not being printed. I am getting the object location

Comment: Check similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575120/no-output-from-process-using-multiprocessing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480498/why-doesnt-print-work-in-python-multiprocessing-pool-map