# Multiprocessing code not showing the desired results

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the multiprocessing in Python and trying to replicate the results of the below code(taken from Corey Schafer youtube video). The code is running but the multiprocessing module is not working. I am using windows 10 and python version 3.8.5 and my laptop has 8 cores.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import workers4
tic=time.time()

processes=[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(50):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=workers4.do_something,args=[20])
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

toc=time.time()
elapsed=toc-tic
print("\nFinished in ",elapsed," seconds")
```

The file workers4.py has the function 'do_something' which makes the    code sleep for some specific time value as passed through the    argument.

```
def do_something(seconds):
    print(f "Sleeping {seconds}second(s)...")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done sleeping...")
```

On running the above code, it shows only
Finished in  `0.8727371692657471`  seconds

and the below statements in `do_something` function in the `workers.py` file are not printed at all not even once.

```
print(f "Sleeping {seconds}second(s)..."), 
print("Done sleeping...")
```

It seems that the do_something function is not getting executed as with a sleep time of 20sec for every process , how can the code execute in 0.8727 secs. Also there are 50 processes in the above code as in the for loop. Can someone help what is the issue and how to rectify it ??

Comment: How are you calling the script? It looks you might not be entering the `if __name__` block.

Comment: By pressing Run

Comment: You could try to remove that `if __name__` line

Comment: @ Quizzarex that name line should be included according to the documentation

Comment: Sure, but for the sake of testing I think it would still run, Python is not as rigid as for instance C-languages.

Comment: @ Quizzarex not working even after removing that if__name__ line

Comment: are you using any ide to run the script?

Comment: @ Krishna Chaurasia No

Comment: you mentioned you are running the script `By pressing Run`. Can you please clarify how are you running it without an ide?

Comment: @ Krishna Chaurasia Python3

Comment: I think that is the ide

Comment: You can also try to put something like `print("Hello MP")` inside your `if __name__ == "__main___":` block of code to see if the inside of that is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your script with both command line and using the IDE (specifically `Spyder`) and I can observe the following differences in behavior.

When I execute the script using command line using `python3 mp.py` which has your code, I can see the output as expected:

```
Finished in  0.0  seconds
Sleeping 2 second(s)...

Finished in  0.0  seconds
Sleeping 2 second(s)...

Finished in  0.0  seconds
Sleeping 2 second(s)...

Finished in  0.0  seconds
Sleeping 2 second(s)...

Finished in  0.0  seconds
Sleeping 2 second(s)...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...

Finished in  3.7699832916259766  seconds
```

When I execute the same script using the `Run` button in `Spyder` IDE, I see only the following output:

```
Finished in  2.8714535236358643  seconds
```

I tried to look for the difference in behavior and found several threads that describe this behavior.

[no-multiprocessing-print-outputs-spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078722/no-multiprocessing-print-outputs-spyder)

There is a specific comments regarding Windows as well:

> That printing with multiprocessing on Windows doesn't work as expected

Also, some IDEs require additional configuration as described for [`IDLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575120/no-output-from-process-using-multiprocessing)

Based on the above observations, I would suggest to try to run the script via command line to verify that the script itself work as expected and try to see if there are any additional configuration needed in the IDE to make it work.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: I am using `Windows 10`.

Comment: Please then tell how to get the expected result as u got in windows

Comment: I used `Powershell` to execute the script using the command `python3 filenameWithPath.py`.

Comment: Can u attach a screenshot

Comment: From where to get powershell ??

Comment: here you go: https://imgur.com/a/jtDFQWK. Powershell is available by default with `Windows 10`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227756/discussion-between-krishna-chaurasia-and-simrandeep-bahal).

Comment: Yes have found powershell, so shall I copy paste the entire python code from python to powershell and run there ?

Answer (score 0):

So I ran this with a few changes and this is running fine. The changes are that I do not have a worker4.py file, changed the waiting time to 1 second. The most significant change was to change the `print(f "Sleeping {seconds}second(s)...")` line to `print(f"Sleeping {seconds}second(s)...")` as I got a syntax error due to the space between the f and the first quote.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
tic=time.time()

processes=[]

def do_something(seconds):
    print(f"Sleeping {seconds}second(s)...")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done sleeping...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(50):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something,args=[1])
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

toc=time.time()
elapsed=toc-tic
print("\nFinished in ",elapsed," seconds")
```

Got the following output

```
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Sleeping 1second(s)...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...

Finished in  1.7538056373596191  seconds
```

Comment: Why is done sleeping in the do_something function not getting printed. and why have u changed the waiting time to 1 sec ? What was your elapsed time ? I tried your code but still not getting your output

Comment: What is your OS and the python version?

Comment: I am not getting these Sleeping 1second(s) command getting printed. I changed the waiting time and it got reflected in the output so code is running fine for me in the background but these commands are not getting printed

Comment: I am using Linux and Python 3.8 for this example. My elapsed time was 1.75 seconds as stated in the printout.

Comment: I am using windows , may be there is a bug in windows