# is_alive always returns false for multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import *
from time import *
def a():
    while(1):
        None

b=Process(target=a)
b.start()
sleep(15)
print b.is_alive()
```

b.is_alive() always prints false,

could someone help me to know how to start this process'

> Update : i was running the code from python IDLE , opening file in
>   IDLE and pressing f5 ,and the code was always throwing false
>
> but when i try to run the code from cmd > python.exe file.py , the
>   code works fine

Comment: Works fine for me. Confirm that `a()` is starting and/or ending by adding some debug statements.

Comment: Add a `__main__` entry point and add a `sleep` into the`while` Loop.

Comment: @mhawke i added debug statement , the function a() doesn't starts at all, it starts only if i explicitly call b.run()

Comment: @stovfl i added if __name__ == '__main__': , and added a print "hello" before while(1) , it seems a() is not at all starting

Comment: Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) this the version i use

Comment: Hi thank you everyone for the reply , i have an update , i was running the code from IDLE , (opening in IDLE and pressing F5) and the code  was not working , but when i try from cmd python.exe file.py , the code works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiprocessing Process class be run from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help