# why multiprocessing function Process doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use the module multiprocessing to execute 2 functions at the same time but it doesn't work. the code in these two functions depends on the library of these two instruments, there has no matter with multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def mesure_rfb():
  libc.StartMeas()
  time.sleep(0.5)
  while libc.Measuring() == -1:
      time.sleep(1)

def mesure_nrt():
  global ave,rev,chrono
  my_nrt.zeroing()
  my_nrt.setimeout(100000)
  tstart = time.time()
  b=2
  ave,rev,chrono = my_nrt.measurement(times=b)
  a=time.time()-tstart
  print('measurement cost: ' , a,' s')
  print('a measurement costs: ' , a/b,' s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  rfb = mp.Process(name='rfb measuring', target=mesure_rfb)
  nrt = mp.Process(name='nrt measuring', target=mesure_nrt)
  rfb.start()
  nrt.start()
  rfb.join()
  nrt.join()
```

As soon as I run this part of my programme, it executes only the function mesure_nrt. I am quite new to python. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No it runs the two concurrently, but the first process does not print nor returns anything.

Comment: What indicates to you that rfb is not running?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in fact, the first function returns some data that I can see in a logiciel connected to an instruments, but in this program, it doesn't show that, Is there any problem with multiprocessing in my program?

Comment: it's running, just correct the indentation

Comment: Sorry that I didn't put the entire code for the first function, but it indeed return something

Comment: Could you tell me what's the best way yo execute two functions at the same time,  with lock or something like this? Thanks very much,

Comment: I tried several times and I find out the problem is that the program above can't execute any function, and I tried other examples, doesn't work neither, I am using IDLE, is the problem of console?

Comment: Relevant: [Can multiprocessing Process class be run from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle)