# Contents are not printed using Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I just want to run an example from [this site](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-multiprocessing-in-python--cms-30281) which is the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def square(x):

    for x in numbers:
        print('%s squared  is  %s' % (x, x**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        numbers = [43, 50, 5, 98, 34, 35]

    p = Process(target=square, args=('x',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print ("Done")
```

it says that if you run the code, you should see the following results:

```
#result
Done
43 squared  is  1849
50 squared  is  2500
5 squared  is  25
98 squared  is  9604
34 squared  is  1156
35 squared  is  1225
```

But as I run this code, I just see `Done` in results and nothing more. In that Tutorial used Python 2.7 but I have 3.6 and I added `()` in prints.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You forgot to call `p.join()` (notice the brackets after `join()`) to wait for the process to finish. Also, in case you didn't make an error when indenting your code on SO, keep in mind that indentation is very important in Python.

Comment: `p.join()` just ensures main process waits for children to finish. So you would see `Done` at the end instead of first print as shown in output by OP. Are you indentations correct? When I ran the same code on my python 3.5.2, it works nicely.

Comment: @zwer I just a typo. the problem is not solved

Comment: @KetanMukadam `()` is added, it was typo. But i do not know why it does not work in my python 3.6.3. I just see `Done`

Comment: @Ehsan Editing simple typos is fine, but you changed quite a bit since you asked your question. Now, the code you have in your question is working which is confusing when one reads the question

Comment: Why do you expect "Done" first?

Comment: @MartinThoma No I corrected two typos. I just copied and pasted an example from the mentioned website. Is my python version has a problem?

Comment: I tried it with "Python 2.7.12" and [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50716403/4) worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your snippet.

1. Identation: `if __name__ == '__main__':` is part of the square function
2. The function`square` should take the argument `numbers` not `x`
3. The arguments passed to the process should be `args=(numbers,)`

Once you fix all this, you get:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def square(numbers):

    for x in numbers:
        print('%s squared  is  %s' % (x, x**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [43, 50, 5, 98, 34, 35]

    p = Process(target=square, args=(numbers,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print ("Done")
```

which runs correctly.

If you use IDLE on Windows, to see the output, you need to start IDLE from the command line:

```
C:\Users\MyName>python -m idlelib
```

as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle)

Comment: In this case I see `Done` Again. I am getting mad. I could not manage to find the problem :((

Comment: Do you think I have to change my Python version?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Copying and pasting the code in the white page of Python and the running it. The results will be appeared in Python shell `>>>` I use IDLE.

Comment: Try to open a command line, go to the directory where your file is saved and type `python myfile.py`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it doesn't run in IDLE on my machine either, I get `module 'idlelib.pyshell' has no attribute 'use_subprocess'`

Comment: So, Where did you run this code when IDLE does not work?

Comment: At the moment I use spyder3 which is pretty good for small snippets, for larger projects I use atom. You can run any script from the command line with `python myscript.py`. If you want spyder under windows, you should get anaconda.

Comment: I think I've found a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle)

Comment: I have Anaconda and this code does not work on `Jupiter`. And I do not understand the command line you told me. I mean I do not understand what should I do.

Comment: Yes this is the exact problem of mine this question mentioned. But Do you know what is consol 2.x.? in the answer of question is mentioned.

Comment: If you are on windows, you can get a terminal with `win+r` and type `cmd`. From there move to the directory where your file is located with `cd c:\Users\Ehsan\mydir` then type `python myfile.py`

Comment: What they mean is `python 2.x` not `console 2.x`.

Comment: so it needs again python 2x. A weakness in Python programming

Comment: No `C:\Users\MyName>python -m idlelib` is for Python 3.x and `C:\Users\MyName>python -m idlelib.idle` is for Python 2.x.

Comment: great, I works. But I have a question. Is there any other way to do? and consider instead of the first print, we write the outputs in a file. after doing this in `idlelib` it will do our order?

Comment: I don't understand. If you have another question post it separately. Long discussions like this one are frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0):

If IDLE quits with no message, and it was not started from a console, try starting from a console (python -m idlelib) and see if a message appears.
For example if your python file is in the Desktop you may write

C:\Users\MyName> Desktop\python-file-name -m idlelib

prss `win + x` and choose `command prompt`.